# I am using SUMIF formula in excel sheet but getting 0 in return

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am using =SUMIF(A143:A208,”*Dinner*”,B143:B208) formula in excel sheet but the onlu output i am getting is 0. can someone tell what the problem is?

**Ignore the values on the far right; also, I have added '*' between 'dinner', but on stackoverflow its not visible

[image]

Comment: There should not be any problem unless you have trailing spaces or non printable characters after the criteria's

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya , how to check for non printable chars? i dont think there are any trailing spaces or non printable chars...

Comment: Have you tried to use `TRIM` and/or `CLEAN` functions? Check this [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/delete-special-unwanted-characters-excel/) too

Comment: Can you upload the workbook here, or a one drive link to check, where is the issue. Because your formula is correct. It should be problem with the data

Comment: `TRIM()` or `CLEAN()` doesnt work with non printable characters, for that you need to use `SUBSTITUTE()` function

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this is what `CLEAN` documentation states: “Removes all nonprintable characters from text”

Comment: May be it says, from my personal experience it doesn't work, I can say 200% . I have used SAP, SQL data and many other kinds where it carries non printable characters and doesnt work.

Comment: Please try your own using `CHAR(160)` with `CLEAN()` function. let me know if that works.

Comment: Also as you have tagged `Office 365`, can you try this once `=SUM(FILTER(B2:B8,SUBSTITUTE(A2:A8,CHAR(160),"")="Dinner"))` assuming the data is from `A2:B8` for example. please change the range as per your suit

Comment: If your data is in rows `2:67`, then you would need to lock (`$`) the rows i.e. `=SUMIF(A$2:A$67,”Dinner”,B$2:B$67)` so when you copy the formula down for the other values it always stays `$2:$67`. If the data is in another worksheet, you need to account for that by using e.g. `=SUMIF(Sheet1!A$2:A$67,”Dinner”,Sheet1!B$2:B$67)`.

Comment: You need to start with your own diagnostics.  What does `=SUM(B143:B208)` return?  That would reveal if Excel is finding numbers as text and for some reason is having trouble re-casting them automatically.  Assuming “dinner” is in cell A144, what does `=A144=“Dinner”` return, and what does `=LEN(A144)` return?  Any time you use a “compound” function like SUMIF and aren’t getting your expected result, test each part of the compound function.

Comment: Pressing `F2` while on the cell, gets your cursor inside the formula bar (at the end of the word/formula. You'll be able to select that character and check for presence in other words.

Comment: So check the contents of cell A144. Does it contain more than dinner? Even len() may help.